# DataTriggerBehavior Binding to Property on ViewModel

Tags: mvvm, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to bind a DataTriggerBehavior to a Property on my ViewModel, but it doesn't ever fire.

I've used DataTriggerBehaviors bound to various Properties of Controls with no trouble but can't get the VM binding to work.

DataContext is set to the VM.
I can see the binding value in debug but nothing triggers.
I've tested the InvokeCommandAction by changing the DataTriggerBehavior to an EventTriggerBehavior so that works fine.

```
                <AppBarButton Icon="Library">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding HelpPhase}" ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="Add" >
                            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.StoreRateCommand, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"/>
                        </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </AppBarButton>
```

In VM (inherits VMBase that implements IPCN)

```
Private mHelpPhase As String
    Public Property HelpPhase() As String
        Get
            Return Settings.HelpPhase
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            SetProperty(Settings.HelpPhase, value)
        End Set
    End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

The `EventTriggerBehavior` listens for a specific event on its source and executes an action when the event is fired. It is different from the `DataTriggerBehavior`.

The `DataTriggerBehavior` performs an action when the data the behaviors is bound to meets a specified condition. In your question, when the bound data of the HelpPhase's value change to "Add", the behavior triggers an action to fire the command.

You should be able check if you have bind the `HelpPhase` to the DataTriggerBehavior and set the "Add" to the `HelpPhase`. You can bind the `HelpPhase` to `Text` property of `TextBlock` if the TextBlock show "Add".

There is an official DataTriggerBehavior sample, please refer the [XamlBehaviors sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors).

Comment: Yes.  No problems with the HelpPhase Binding but..I attempted to simplify my original post for clarity, but I'm now wondering if some of my omissions might be important.

The Behavior is actually implemented in a Style and I'm wondering if this could be why the DataTriggerBehavior isn't working.  As I said earlier ,EventTriggerBehaviors work fine.  I'm guessing that an EventTriggerBahavior Tapped event references the tapped control, yet maybe a DataTriggerBehavior does not ?

Comment: Perhaps I should post what I'd actually like to do.  

I have a row of buttons sharing a common Style.  Each button's BorderColor can animate when a Property in the View Model named FlashButton changes, such that if FlashButton="Button2", then the button named Button2 will flash.

My current (not working solution) was to put the Storyboard in a custom Visual State in the Style and use GoToStateAction through a DataTriggerBehavior that checks if the FlashProperty Property is equal to the Name of the Button.